# Python multiprocessing changed variable but not update?

Tags: python

I'm from Taiwan, English is not good, sorry.

I tried the following portion of code, and you can see that I printed memory address.

These two memory address was the same, but when `best_action` returning ,
it was error, because `self.root.children` list was empty.

But the `v = self.tree_policy()` had added item into children list. What cause this error? Thanks.

```
class MonteCarloTreeSearch:

    def __init__(self, node: MonteCarloTreeSearchNode):
        self.root = node

    def best_action(self, simulations_number):
        p = list()
        for i in range(0, simulations_number):
            p.append(Process(target=self.simulate))
            p[i].start()

        for j in range(0, simulations_number):
            p[j].join()
        print(hex(id(self.root.children)))
        return self.root.best_child()

    def simulate(self):
        v = self.tree_policy()
        reward = v.rollout()  # who win?
        # exploitation only
        v.backpropagate(reward)
        print(hex(id(self.root.children)))
```

Comment: What's the error? What's the input? How are `MonteCarloTreeSearchNode` and `Process` defined? And how are you instantiating an object from this class and calling the methods?

Comment: error is return `self.root.best_child()` . This method will found the `self.root.children` list element which is max. But this list was empty so it caused error.

Comment: `Process` is `from multiprocessing import Process` and `MonteCarloTreeSearchNode` is a class.  The detailed code is on this github [link](https://github.com/int8/monte-carlo-tree-search) I used this coder's MCTS code. And I want to implement it with parallel computation. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sub-processes do not share the same memory space as the parent process. You should use multi-threading with the `threading` module instead for your purpose.

```
from threading import Thread
```

then change:

```
p.append(Process(target=self.simulate))
```

to:

```
p.append(Thread(target=self.simulate))
```

Be wary of race conditions between the threads, however, since all threads share the same memory space. You should make the code thread-safe by using `threading.Lock` or `threading.RLock` around operations that updates objects that are shared among threads.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I had tried thread to implement. It just used one CPU core to compute. I want to use multicore to compute, so I need multiprocessing. The MCTS is a tree. I think I need to creat a shared memory to store the tree's root node. But how can I do?